# Can't override flutter dependency in windows

Tags: flutter, web, window, gis, google-signin

I'm trying to override google_sign_in dependency to migrate to the new gis library based on this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/88084). Here's the dependcy override i defined

[image]

Yet somehow when i run pub get, this error appears

[image]

I can run pub get normally in my linux machine, this only happens on windows. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

[`Full pubspec.yaml`](https://pastebin.com/1R5QWfd8)

Comment: can you show your entire `pubspec.yaml` ?

Comment: sure thing, i added the full file in the post